# Existance of a 3 x 3 matrix with zero trace, such that $A^2-A^t=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Study if there is a matrix $ A\in M_{3}(\mathbb{R}) $ so that $ \operatorname{tr}(A)=0 $ and $ A^{2}-A^{t}=I_{3}. $

So far, I found that $ A^{3}+\operatorname{tr}(A^{*})\cdot A^{2}-\det(A)\cdot I_{3}=0 $, $ \operatorname{tr}(A^{2})=3 $, $  (\det(A))^{2}=\det(A)+ \operatorname{tr}(A^{*})+1 $ and $ \operatorname{tr}(A^{3})=3\cdot \det(A). $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $A^2-A^t=I$ then $A^t=A^2-I$ and $(A^t)^2=(A^t+I)^t=A+I$. Combinning this we get : $(A^2-I)^2=A+I$, then $A(A+I)(A^2-A-1)=0$.If $A$ exists then $A$ is diagonalizable and  $\text{Spec}(A) \subset \{0,-1,\Phi,-\Phi^{-1}\}$ where $\Phi=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$ is the gold number.

After analyzing all cases, to have  a nul trace (which also requires $\text{tr}(A^2)=3$ since $A^2=A^t+I$), $A$ must be simillar to the diagonal matrix:$$B=\begin{pmatrix} -1&0&0\\0&\Phi&0 \\ 0&0&-\Phi^{-1}  \end{pmatrix}$$ But $\text{tr}(B^2)=1+\Phi^2+\Phi^{-2} =1+\frac 14((\sqrt 5  +1)^2+(\sqrt 5 -1)^2)=4$

But we have $\text{tr} A^2 =3$ who contredicts the last relation with $\text{tr}(B^2)$ (since $A$  and  $B$  have the same trace).